# In interior point solver we can set unity constraint as x1+x2+x3+x4=1 can we set constraint like 0.10<=x1+x3>=0.80 and 0.20<=x2+x4>=0.50

Tags: mathematical-optimization, portfolio

In interior point solver we can set unity constraint like x1+x2+x3+x4=1 can we set constraint like 0.10<= x1+x3 >=0.80 and 0.20<=x2+x4>=0.50 using setcoefficient.

Please provide the sample to set constraint of weight boundaries on sector and security both level.

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/InteriorPointSolver/AddRow/php-interiorpointsolver-addrow-method-examples.html

We have used code of InteriorPointSolver for Markowitz model, It has solved to Minimize or Maximize on Security.
But we can not set setbound on sum of some of subset of all securities.
We tried to set constraint using Setcoefficient but it's not working. Please provide the sample for it

Comment: Portfolio Optimization using Markowitz model  by Microsoft Solver Foundation 3

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange looking constraint.

```
0.10 <= x1+x3 >= 0.80
```

can be restated as

```
x1+x3 >= 0.10 
x1+x3 >= 0.80
```

or just

```
x1+x3 >= 0.80
```

No sweat!

---

If the poster really means:

```
0.10 <= x1+x3 <= 0.80
```

(it always helps to reread your question!) then we can write this as:

```
x1+x3 >= 0.10
x1+x3 <= 0.80
```

This is trivial to implement.

If the length of the summation is long:

```
0.10 <= x1+x2+x3+... <= 0.8
```

there is a better approach:

```
y in [0.1,0.8]     (extra variable with lower and upper bounds)
y = x1+x2+x3+...   (single equality constraint)
```

This prevents having the long summation twice in the model. Basically we create an extra variable but save a constraint and the corresponding nonzero coefficients.

---

Of course Microsoft Solver Foundation should not be used in real projects: it has been discontinued in 2012.

Comment: In interior point solver we can set unity constraint like x1+x2+x3+x4=1 can we set constraint like 0.10<= x1+x3 <=0.80 and 0.20<=x2+x4<=0.50 using setcoefficient.

Comment: Please help in C# code to set 0.10<= x1+x3 <=0.80 and 0.20<=x2+x4<=0.50

Comment: That is different than what is stated in the question.

Comment: Yes that was mistake.. we want to set min and max boundaries on set of assets.

Comment: Like we can set boundary on sector level addition to security/script level

Comment: If we add new variable then   int unity;
            solver.AddRow("Investments sum to one", out unity);
            solver.SetBounds(unity, 1, 1); will it work?

Comment: We have to use solver.equal to define new variable with x1,x2,x3?

Comment: Other features of Markowitz method get solved by code in https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/InteriorPointSolver/AddRow/php-interiorpointsolver-addrow-method-examples.html except summation of subset.

Comment: then what should get used for portfolio optimization?

Comment: solver.AddVariable("LE", out assetallocations[0]);
            solver.SetBounds(assetallocations[0], 0.10, 0.80);
            solver.Equals(assetallocations[0] = allocations[0] + allocations[2]);
            solver.AddVariable("GE", out assetallocations[1]);
            solver.SetBounds(assetallocations[1], 0.20, 0.50);
            solver.Equals(assetallocations[1] = allocations[1] + allocations[3]);